# Как найти значение по вводу с клавиатуры ключа в Hashmap?

Tags: java, java-hashmap

Пытаюсь решить следующую задачу. Программа:

- Хранит названия месяцев и их номера в HashMap
- Получает на ввод с клавиатуры название месяца
- Выводит на экран номер месяца, например

  > May is 5 month

Как можно сопоставить номер названию месяца?

Comment: Вы всё ещё можете переформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Старайтесь формулировать задачи чётко и структурированно. Всегда пытайтесь сначала решить задачу самостоятельно, спрашивайте о том, что у вас не получается. Прикладывайте код попытки решения. Тогда будет больше плюсов и меньше минусов. Ну и вы будете гораздо быстрее учиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("January", 1);
map.put("February", 2);
map.put("March", 3);
map.put("April", 4);
map.put("May", 5);
map.put("June", 6);
map.put("July", 7);
map.put("August", 8);
map.put("September", 9);
map.put("October", 10);
map.put("November", 11);
map.put("December", 12);
BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
// будем полагать что на вход всегда поступает именно строка с месяцем в правильной форме
String month = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(month + " is " + map.get(month) + " month");
```

Comment: Ответ вроде правильный. Минусы наверняка были «воспитательного характера» — за ответ на плохо сформулированный вопрос с признаками «решайте за меня, мне лень».

Comment: Рекомендую не отвечать на такое — автор должен научиться корректно формулировать свою проблему. Мы же не платная техподдержка, чтобы угадывать мысли. ))

Comment: Да это задача с javarush.ru, я ее сразу узнал и накатал решение, которое проходит там проверку :)